# Are others encountering resource availability issues in us-east1-b?

Tags: google-compute-engine

While attempting to start up compute instances in `us-east1-b`, we're repeatedly but intermittently getting an error code `ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUxSTED_WITH_DETAILS` which [google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability) indicates is due to lack of resource availability. We used to be able to fill our CPU quota, but now only a small fraction are available at any given point. Other regions allowed us to start new instances and we are nowhere near any of our project quotas, so it seems that Google itself doesn't have the resources available to allocate in this zone - but we're wondering if other projects are also hitting the same issues to confirm.

Comment: The problem can be as simple as you are using an instance size that is very popular.

Answer (score 0):

It may occur at some point with other Projects in time where there is a spike in demand for such machines in a region.

Google Cloud Platform also offer a feature called [reservations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) that provides a very high level of assurance in obtaining capacity on Google Cloud Platform.